# Error "Index out of range" in MySQL Workbench 6.0.8.11354 (6.0), what is wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I just started designing a database in `MySQLWorkbench 6.0`. I created a few tables but now when I click the "Add table" button it shows a message: `"Index out of range"` and the program crashes.

Any idea what is wrong or what could I have done to get this error ?

None of the tables have any values, they just have the fields and field type, with their primary keys and foreign keys (something tells me it's something I did when connecting tables via the foreign keys, I'm new to this software).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please show the code, usually something is out of range for example if you are trying to call array[location-100] but there is only 50 spaces you would get that error. same logic goes for SQL. Post your code sample that you are trying to run

Comment: I do still have this issue too, happens frequently when adding a new table in the Diagram tool.

Comment: Likewise. Using the visual editor to add tables. Double-clicking the table after creating triggers the "index out of range" and a hard crash. Happens intermittently. Next time it happens I'll post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried restarting MySQL Workbench? I haven't heard of such a problem before, but maybe steps you did in a certain order caused this exception.

In any case you should file a bug report for it at http://bugs.mysql.com to get this fixed. Only via such a report developers can take notice.

Comment: Restarted and worked fine. Seems like it was some type of bug, submitting report right away, thanks!

Comment: @salsadeanguila did you submit a report? I'm seeing the same bug, and restarting doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 25):

Once the alert popped up, I hit ok and then clicked on the little wrench icon above the utf selection. I had to change how it would separate the columns from ';' to ',' 
This fixed my issue without having to change any of the content in the csv.

Comment: I didn't even realize the wrench was clickable, thanks for the tip.

Comment: MySQLWorkbench CSV export does not escape quotes as well. I don't know why they dont export in a format they can accept as imports. JSON format looks better for now

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into this, Some of the fields in my CSV contained " and ' characters. Removing those fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue, I had to find and remove all sets of "", aka empty string.

Comment: Same here. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been so long already but my issue was solved after opening the cvs as an excel (calc in linux) then saving as csv again.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with the delimiter settings on the wizard until it worked, had to change from ';' to ',' for it to work.

Comment: Could you add a little more context to this please?

Comment: Sure also i'm on MySQL 8 Workbench, not 6 as OP.

1) Right-click on the table and go to 'Table Data Import Wizard'
2) Select the csv file to upload
3) Select the destination table in MySQL
4) Click the spanner icon, go down to 'Field Separator' and change to ','  so that that source columns and dest columns below match up.

If this also doesn't work due to having commas in your csv file, you can try converting the CSV file to JSON using an online utility tool and uploading that instead. Note: MySQL may not be able to find the JSON file so you may have to type the path manually.

Answer (score 1):

Once error shows up click OK
Click on settings icon
Change field separator as per your csv

Done ! It worked for me

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

Answer (score -1):

MySQL workbench 6.3
I had to put all of my column values in "". After I could import data.
Hope help!